# Keep transaction between web service calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, transactions

I have a webservice (Service.svc.cs) in ASP.NET 4.5.1.

I have one method called
"public string UploadData(Guid id, string[] data)"

The client calls this method with strings and the server stores the data in a SQL-Server database, but does not commit or rollback this DbTransaction.

The same client should then (for example 5 seconds later) call one of two other methods:
"CommitData(Guid id)" or 
"RollbackData(Guid id)"

Depending on method, the server should commit or rollback the transaction. If the client does not call within 30 seconds, the transaction should be rolled back.

I have tried storing the transaction in memory in server between calls, but the transaction gets corrupt. Some values in the transaction, like connection gets reset to null. So the commit or rollback does not work.

What is the best way to preserve the System.Data.Common.DbTransaction between web service calls?

Comment: Do you have many clients, or only one?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is,

1. Set `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]` attribute to service class
2. Create class `TransactionData { DbTransaction, StartDate }`
3. Create a `static` dictionary, `IDictionary<GUID, TransactionData> transactions;`
4. When user calls 1st method, store transaction to this dictionary with some Newly create guid, and return guid to user
5. On other calls, user send this guid to server, check if transaction exist commit or rollback
6. Create a separate thread, or on every user call, check and rollback/clear Dictionary for old transactions...

You can try to user Session, instead of Dictionary... anyway  if you are hosting under IIS, there is almost no way to keep persistent data except external storage... but this can work for your case

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems that threading is not intended to be used with web service. But I got it to work thanks to your help!